# Syntax error on token(s)

Tags: animation, syntax, imageview, token

I'm trying to make an image move from left to right and right to left. This is the code I have:

```
    package com.example.;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class PlayActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
}
ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

  TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f);
  animation.setDuration(5000);
  animation.setRepeatCount(5);
  animation.setRepeatMode(2);
  animation.setFillAfter(true);
  imageView2.startAnimation(animation);
```

However on the last 5 lines it gives me these errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token "5000", delete this 
     token
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "5", delete this 
     token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token "2", delete this 
     token
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "true", delete this 
     token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token "animation", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
     this token
```

Could somebody tell me what to fix? besides those 5 lines everything seems to be okay

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me now

```
    package com.example.;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    public class PlayActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        }
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f);
        protected TranslateAnimation setanimation(TranslateAnimation animation)
        {
            animation.setDuration(5000);
            animation.setRepeatCount(5);
            animation.setRepeatMode(2);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            imageView2.startAnimation(animation);
            return animation;
        }

}
```

The issue was that you where trying to set the animations properties outside of a function body. So i fixed it by creating the function `protected TranslateAnimation setanimation(TranslateAnimation animation)`to hold the code where you are setting the animations properties and now it compiles and runs fine although i don't know what your expected output is.

Hope this helps